# SQL Server stored procedure passing old values not new value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

This is my table:

```
search_id search_term clicked count
------------------------------
1        rabbit        0         5
2        airline       1         4
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```sql
alter procedure update_item
    (@search_id int,
     @search_term varchar(50),
     @clicked int)
as
begin
    update search_events 
    set search_term= @search_term,
        clicked = @clicked
    where search_id = @search_id
end

--exec update_item @search_id=1,@search_term='rabbit',@clicked=0
```

I created a stored procedure and I pass two parameters.

I want to pass only one of parameter to update the record and second parameter value will be old value.

It is possible that passing the parameter with the old value.

For example:

```sql
exec update_item @search_id= 1, @search_term= 'pass here old value that it is rabbit', @clicked = 1
```

Update only clicked value that it is 1 from 0.

Comment: I really suggest fixing the typographical error in the parameter `@serachid`; such errors can make debugging a *real* problem in the future when you spell `searchid` correctly.

Comment: If your search_id is a unique key then you do not need your second parameter at all.  If you only want to update clicked then just use `update search_events set clicked=@clicked where search_id=@serachid`.

Comment: What is your end goal here? Do you want to make an optional parameter that will default to 'rabbit' if not specified?

Comment: Perhaps `@searchitem` needs to have a default value (`NULL`?) and then you can use `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` in the `SET` clause?

Comment: @jonathanwillcock sir i'm using store proc with passing parameter, and in that parameter are compulsory, in some cases it is important and some cases it is not, there for i need solution to maintain the old value.

Comment: @ortiga yes i need  passed the parameter but non change value and change value both

Comment: So does my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75134100/sql-server-stored-procedure-passing-old-values-not-new-value?noredirect=1#comment132587827_75134100) not address that, @NandkumarGaikwad ? if not, then you need to further explain your question and make it clear what behaviour you are after with an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a single parameter, you can use a simple if statement, and omit the set clause if the value is null

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_item (
    @search_id INT
    ,@search_term VARCHAR(50)
    ,@clicked INT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@search_term IS NULL)
        UPDATE search_events
        SET clicked = @clicked
        WHERE search_id = @search_id
    ELSE
        UPDATE search_events
        SET search_term = @search_term
            ,clicked = @clicked
        WHERE search_id = @search_id
END
```

If you have more parameters that you need to check, then you'd need to build the update statement dynamically. A basic example as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE update_item (
    @search_id INT
    ,@search_term VARCHAR(50)
    ,@clicked INT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000) = N'UPDATE search_events SET ',
            @Params NVARCHAR(300) = N'@search_id INT, @search_term VARCHAR(50), @clicked INT'
    
    IF (@search_term IS NOT NULL)
        SET @Sql = @Sql + ' search_term = @search_term,'

    SET @Sql = @Sql + ' clicked = @clicked'

    SET @Sql = @Sql + ' WHERE search_id = @search_id' 
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, @Params, @search_id=@search_id, @search_term=@search_term, @clicked=@clicked
END
```